# prove $(a,0)_{complex} = a$ by definition of complex numbers (as stated in Rudin 1.24)?

Tags: real-analysis

Characteristic property of complex numbers (Rudin 1.24),

$(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b)(c,d) =(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ for all $a,b,c,d \in R$

Additional axioms from 1.25

$(0,0)=0$ and $(1,0)=1$

Prove

$(a,0) = a$ for all $a \in R$ ..[1]

---

In 1.28 while prove $i^2 = -1$ Rudin just equals $(-1,0)=-1$ which i cant prove. Morever, 1.29

$(a,bi) = a + bi$ uses [1].

So, what am i missing ?

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed under scalar multiplication. $a = a*1 = a(1,0) = (a,0)$.

Comment: To prove that $(-1,0) = -1$, you can write

$$ (-1,0) + 1 = (-1,0) + (1,0) = (-1+1,0) = (0,0) = 0$$

So that 

$$ (-1,0) = -1$$